# How to load second tab by default when using PagerSlidingTabStrip in android

Tags: android, fragment, pagerslidingtabstrip

I need to create a UI just like below.

[image]

When I write the code and run the application, it loads first tab which is "Categories". What I need is to load second tab, which is "Home" when I run the application without changing the Tab order.

Below is my code.

Comment: If you are using ViewPager then try `pager.setCurrentItem(1);`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't matter if it's PagerSlidingTabStrip or another, what you need is to set the current item of your viewpager :

```
setCurrentItem(int item)
```

Set the currently selected page.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to make second tab as default tab.

```
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
```

it works.